# Accessing two returned values in Django view

Tags: django

I have my form `clean` method return two values. How do I distinguish the two variables in my view. Basically, I want to use the form data to check the database and return an object if it exists so that I can pass it to a new view. My goal is to not hit the database twice, once to see if the object exists and another time to retrieve it to display to the user.

Forms.py

```
class DocumentCodeLookup(forms.Form):
    code = forms.CharField(max_length=15, error_messages={'required': 'Whoops! Please enter the Document Code from your ticket.'})

    def clean_code(self):
        code = self.cleaned_data['code'].upper()
        if (re.match(r'^[A-Z0-9]{4,8}[-][A-Z0-9]{6}$',code)):
            code_parts = code.split('-')

            try:
                q = Code.objects.get( user_defined_code__name=code_parts[0], document_code=code_parts[1] )
            except Code.DoesNotExist:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Hmmm, we couldn't find that document.")

            else:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Hmmm, we couldn't find that document.")
        return code, q
```

Views.py

```
def index(request):
    code_lookup_form = DocumentCodeLookup()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        code_lookup_form = DocumentCodeLookup(request.POST)
        if code_lookup_form.is_valid:
            redirect('document', x = q) # I want to pass the returned object to the view

    return render_to_response('base/splash_page.html' ,{
            'code_lookup_form'      :       code_lookup_form
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: First, Django uses caching.  Twice is a non-issue.  Second, did you measure this?  Is it your number one bottleneck?

Comment: I'm not sure I see where you're assigning the value of 'q' as returned by the clean_code() method on the form in the view. It would seem like you'd need to pass in the request context to the form, and then add q to the context, or, set a property on the form for q, that you can then pick up in the view after form.is_valid()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will clean_field even work like that?

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

Note the comment.

You can put the attr on the form with `self`.

```
class DocumentCodeLookup(forms.Form):
    code = forms.CharField(max_length=15, error_messages={'required': 'Whoops! Please enter the Document Code from your ticket.'})

    def clean_code(self):
        code = self.cleaned_data['code'].upper()
        if (re.match(r'^[A-Z0-9]{4,8}[-][A-Z0-9]{6}$',code)):
            code_parts = code.split('-')

            self.q = None
            try:
                self.q = Code.objects.get( user_defined_code__name=code_parts[0], document_code=code_parts[1] )
            except Code.DoesNotExist:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Hmmm, we couldn't find that document.")

            else:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Hmmm, we couldn't find that document.")
        return code
```

`q` is on the form.

```
def index(request):
    code_lookup_form = DocumentCodeLookup()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        code_lookup_form = DocumentCodeLookup(request.POST)
        if code_lookup_form.is_valid():
            redirect('document', x = code_lookup_form.q) # <---

    return render_to_response('base/splash_page.html' ,{
            'code_lookup_form'      :       code_lookup_form
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great. I was trying to make it a lot more complicated than it needed to be.